# Spring compressed by external constant force,pot.energy stored over it is half of the work done by force, where does half gone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, work, friction, spring

I have a doubt that for an ideal (massless)spring if apply an constant force over it until equilibrium the energy stored over it is ( kx^2)/2 and the work done by force is kx^2 so where the half of the energy gone
Also in thermodynamics work done on the gas when a gas is compressed due to a constant pressure over it is Pext(Vf -Vi) irreversibly,why here all the external work is considered
Both question are interrelated and contradictory to each other
I have an inside feeling that the work in second case should not be be equal to Pext(Vf -Vi) as initially the opposing force is less than that of external one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass dropped on a spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266129/)

Comment: See also [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507004), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127002), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453239), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616055/146039), [5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/664191), [6](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660245), [7](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278462), [8](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579993). [This previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616055/146039) contains a long list of such factor-of-two questions.